# Error when installing material ui in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use material ui core but I am getting an error when installing it with npm in a react and typescript application.
The command I used in the root of the project is:
`npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled`

[Material UI website](https://mui.com/)

The error I got is:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @mui/core@5.0.0-alpha.54
npm ERR! Found: @types/react@18.0.15
npm ERR! node_modules/@types/react
npm ERR!   peerOptional @types/react@"^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from @mui/base@5.0.0-alpha.95
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/base
npm ERR!     @mui/base@"5.0.0-alpha.95" from @mui/material@5.10.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       @mui/material@"^5.10.3" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (@mui/icons-material)
npm ERR!   peerOptional @types/react@"^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.10.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!     @mui/icons-material@"^5.10.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   9 more (@mui/private-theming, @mui/system, @mui/types, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional @types/react@"^16.8.6 || ^17.0.0" from @mui/core@5.0.0-alpha.54
npm ERR! node_modules/@mui/core
npm ERR!   @mui/core@"^5.0.0-alpha.54" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @types/react@17.0.49
npm ERR! node_modules/@types/react
npm ERR!   peerOptional @types/react@"^16.8.6 || ^17.0.0" from @mui/core@5.0.0-alpha.54
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/core
npm ERR!     @mui/core@"^5.0.0-alpha.54" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/username/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/username/.npm/_logs/2022-09--debug-0.log
user@User'sPC projectName % npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @mui/core@5.0.0-alpha.54
npm ERR! Found: @types/react@18.0.15
npm ERR! node_modules/@types/react
npm ERR!   peerOptional @types/react@"^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from @mui/base@5.0.0-alpha.95
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/base
npm ERR!     @mui/base@"5.0.0-alpha.95" from @mui/material@5.10.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       @mui/material@"^5.10.3" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (@mui/icons-material)
npm ERR!   peerOptional @types/react@"^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.10.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!     @mui/icons-material@"^5.10.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   9 more (@mui/private-theming, @mui/system, @mui/types, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional @types/react@"^16.8.6 || ^17.0.0" from @mui/core@5.0.0-alpha.54
npm ERR! node_modules/@mui/core
npm ERR!   @mui/core@"^5.0.0-alpha.54" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @types/react@17.0.49
npm ERR! node_modules/@types/react
npm ERR!   peerOptional @types/react@"^16.8.6 || ^17.0.0" from @mui/core@5.0.0-alpha.54
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/core
npm ERR!     @mui/core@"^5.0.0-alpha.54" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/username/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/username/.npm/_logs/2022-09-debug-0.log
```

My relevant package.json is:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@mui/core": "^5.0.0-alpha.54",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.3",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.10.3",
},
```

I removed the `@mui/core dependency` and then tried the command: `npm i --save @mui/core` as suggested by the answer in the comment, however I got the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving:projectname@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.2" from @mui/core@5.0.0-alpha.54
npm ERR! node_modules/@mui/core
npm ERR!   @mui/core@"^5.0.0-alpha.54" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/username/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/username/.npm/_logs/2022-09--debug-0.log
```

I have no idea what this error means so would appreciate any help thanks!

Comment: Please show your `package.json` too. I suspect you have an incompatible version of `@mui/core` there.

Comment: @AKX Sure I have just edited it in at the end of the question. Thanks

Comment: try npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled

Comment: @Travis Okay. Remove the `@mui/core` dependency, then install a compatible non-alpha version of it with `npm i --save @mui/core`.

Comment: @AKX Thanks, I tried that but it did not work:( I edited in the error I got at the end of the question since it did not fit here.

Comment: @Eldho I tried that and got the error in the question

Comment: which node version your using

Comment: @Eldho I'm using v16.15.1

Answer (score -1):

**Run these command**

1. npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
2. npm i --save @mui/core
3. npm i @mui/styles

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).